# Sentence from 'The Plague' novel

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

Sentence is

> "He was deterred by the thought that not one of his sufferings but was common to all the others and that in a world where sorrow is so often lonely this was an advantage".

I don't understand this 'but' use. I know he wants to say all of his sufferings were common but what exactly is this usage of 'but'. Is it an error? TIA

Comment: Please note: That novel is a translation from the French. You could look for a better one.

Comment: The one I am reading is done by Stuart Gilbert.

Comment: I would look for others. I believe that was the first and not considered to me the best.

Comment: Translation of most of the parts is really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels like a strain in the translation. In order to make it work in my mind, I have to process it further:

> He was deterred by the thought that [there was] not one of his sufferings [except that it] was common to all the others ...

That's still rather a precious and poorly put together statement in modern English, but at least now it has a bit more glue holding it together. In plainer words, it means

> There existed not a single one of his sufferings that was not like all the others.

and, even plainer:

> All his problems were more or less the same.

This relies on the use of *but* meaning *except that*:

> **but** *conj*
>   4. With the exception that; except that. Often used with that: *would have joined the band but he couldn't spare the time; would have resisted but that they lacked courage.*
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/but)</sub>

Comment: You still get this kind of use of ***but*** in contexts like ***It never rains but it pours***, but I think outside of poetic/literary contexts it only really turns up in such "frozen" utterances today (completely different to ***It never rains but it sometimes snows there***).